# error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, compilation, memset

I am trying to compile the complete example 8 provided at the end of this page: http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/cmpfit.html

but I am getting this error: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope

I have been looking how to solve this error and I saw that some people solved it by adding `#include <string.h>` to the head of the code. I tried it but I am still getting the same error.

I am using gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

I am trying to compile with:

```
g++ -o example example.cpp -lmpfit -lm
```

Comment: you need to add <string.h> header - if you haven't done so already? Also, do this `g++ -g -Wall example.cpp -o example.o -lmpfit -lm`. Please show us how you are doing `memset` with the actual printout of the message.

Comment: Yes, I have already added <string.h>. I still see the same error. By adding -g -Wall in the compilation order I additionally got this error: example.cpp:59:10: warning: unused variable ‘pactual’ [-Wunused-variable]

Comment: That code snippet will not compile by itself. You need to insert it as a part of a function - "example 8" shows a pretty complete program which should compile out-of-the-box.

Comment: You should use `std::memset();`.

Comment: The code I am currently trying to compile is exactly that of the example 8 in the web site. I only added the line #include <string.h> to the head. The error message I got is: example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
example.cpp:66:34: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: I tried with std::memset but I am still getting the same error... This is my line 68 at this moment:   std::memset(&result,0,sizeof(result));

Comment: The error is still the same: example.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’: example.cpp:66:34: error: ‘memset’ was not declared in this scope

Answer (score 10):

If you use C you should include string.h

Otherwise, if you use C++ you should use cstring

```
C: #include <string.h>

C++: #include <cstring>
```

Comment: You should use `#include <string.h>` in both C and C++, if you want to use `::memset`.  `#include <cstring>` gets you `std::memset`, and if it also makes `::memset` available, it does so by accident.  The Standard permits it but does not require it to do so.

Comment: Now I have both includes #include <string.h>,
#include <cstring> and std::memset. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Please give us in a paste.bin the source code of your program. I will try to compile it with gcc in my PC.

Comment: Hi, the code is exactly the "example 8" that appears at the end of this web page: http://www.physics.wisc.edu/~craigm/idl/cmpfit.html. I have just added #include <string.h> and/or #include <cstring> and tried with "std::memset" instead of "memset"

Comment: I added "#include <string.h>" and I compiled it with gcc without errors.

Answer (score 1):

I updated gcc to gcc-4.9 and I could compile just adding "#include " to the head of the code. Then I tried with gcc-4.8 and gcc-4.7, and again I was able to compile the code with no problem. Perhaps my previous compiler (gcc-4.6) was not correctly installed?¿. I will keep working with the last version of gcc. Thank you all for your help.